# Javascript to scroll an iPython Notebook cell to the top of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jupyter-notebook

I'm using iPython to present to my class. I know about converting to Reveal.js slideshows but I don't want to do that because I want to be able to edit the cells live in answer to questions.

It is working OK just moving from cell to cell but it would be so much smoother if I could hit a key to move to the next cell **and** scroll the window so the cell is at the top.

I'm sure this must be possible by adding a bit of javascript to custom.js but before I dive in, I thought I would ask if anyone had already done something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions) `slidemode` extension in `slidemode` folder. If you saw some scipy talk, this is what Fernando Perez/ Paul Ivanov and some other people use.